# Qual seria uma palavra que expressa a ideia de relatar uma situação fazendo-a parecer pior que realmente é?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, vocabulário

Então, qual seria tal palavra? Por exemplo, imagine uma situação em que uma pessoa A conta a seu amigo, pessoa B, que uma janela em sua casa quebrou e sua substituição será um tanto custosa. A pessoa B, então, conta a seu amigo, pessoa C que "a janela da pessoa A explodiu e sua reposição poderá possivelmente levar A à falência." Procuro uma palavra que não seja "exagerar", visto que essa não carrega obrigatoriamente uma conotação negativa.

Comment: Hipérbole ou auxese é a figura de linguagem que incide quando há exagero propositado em um conceito para definir algo de forma dramática, transmitindo uma ideia aumentada do autêntico. Em termos simplificados, a hipérbole consiste na expressão evidentemente exagerada de uma ideia.

Answer (score 8):

Não ficou claro o contexto (*formal*? *informal*? *jurídico*? *profissional*?), mas `dramatizar` tem um significado próximo do que você procura. A palavra em si não tem um significado literal negativo (por exemplo, *dramatizar um livro*), mas tem a *conotação negativa* que você procura.

> "Não seja tão pessimista, pessoa B, você está dramatizando a situação."

Acho um pouco formal demais para falar com um amigo, porém. Seria melhor dizer `fazer drama`.

> "Não seja tão pessimista, pessoa B, você está fazendo drama [da situação]."

Comment: Complementando: o dicionário Priberam reconhece a expressão "[fazer (um) drama](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/drama)".

Answer (score 2):

Para o exemplo que tu dás, "a janela explodiu", eu costumo usar a expressão **"fazer terrorismo psicológico"**.

- Fulano gosta de **fazer terrorismo psicológico**. Não é capaz de contar alguma coisa sem aumentar dez vezes os aspectos negativos.

Temos também um provérbio de conotação neutra:

- "Quem conta um conto, aumenta um ponto".

Answer (score 2):

Se me permitem vou sugerir uma expressão idiomática.

Você está fazendo uma tempestade no copo d'agua. É uma expressão de uso recorrente para expressar a dramatização de determinado acontecimento.

> Nesta frase, figurativamente, um grande e intenso fen{#ó|ô}meno
>   meteorológico ocorre num pequeno recipiente de água, apresentando,
>   portanto, um contraste muito evidente. Como se trata de uma
>   impossibilidade fisica, mostra-se que há reacções ou preocupações que
>   são desproporcionadas em relação à pouca relevância dos seus motivos.

[ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-expressao-fazer-uma-tempestade-num-copo-de-agua/23358)

Answer (score 1):

Exacerbar a situação. Significa descrever a situação com exagero.

Answer (score 0):

"dramatizar" não é adequado, porque dramatizar está relacionado a "encenar uma peça"

"terrorismo psicológico" também não está adequado, porque isso só aconteceria se, no caso do exemplo, a idéia for "agredir" a pessoa C.

Acho que a melhor definição seria exagerar, exorbitar,abusar, e "Exacerbar".

Comment: terrorismo psicológico está a ser usado no sentido figurativo pelo Centaurus.

Comment: Não concordo com a tua crítica sobre *dramatizar*. [Segundo o dicionário Priberam](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/dramatizar), *dramatizar* pode tanto estar relacionado tanto (1) com "tornar dramático, comovente ou interessante" como (2) com "encenar uma peça". Aliás, [ainda segundo o Priberam](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/drama), *fazer um drama* é "exagerar a gravidade ou o aspecto negativo de algo."

Comment: você não concorda comigo por escrever "encenar uma peça" mas concorda com o Priberam por escrever "(2) com 'encenar uma peça'." ? Além disso, a pergunta é sobre "fazendo-a parecer pior" e não "dramática, comovente ou interessante".

Comment: @CorreadaSilva Voce nao deve ter visto bem o segundo link de ANeves. Mais uma vez fazer um drama está a ser usado no sentido figurativo `[Figurado]  Exagerar a gravidade ou o aspecto negativo de algo.`